# list view instead of filling whole screen

Tags: android

I have trying  to create a list with items. I do not want the list will fill the whole screen. I really tries to create a list its width and height will be nearly equal size of the longest list item and number of items on the list respectively. In other words;

if I have one item, on android I will see

```
------------------------
     |      |
     | 1    |





------------------------
```

If I have 2 items

```
------------------------
     |      |
     | 1    |
     | 2    |




------------------------
```

If I have item with name "lll" and "llllllllll",

```
------------------------
     |               |
     | lll           |
     | llllllllll    |




------------------------
```

My layout is

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="10dp" >
 </TextView>
```

What part should I change in order to get what I have told at above ?

EDIT:

```
 String[] values = new String[] { "1", "2", "3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14" };
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, values);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: and where is the xml with listview defined? have you tried setting its witdth also to wrap_content?

Answer (score 1):

You probably have the width attribute of your ListView set to 'fill_parent' or 'match_parent'.  The Layout you included in your original question is for an element in your ListView.

Bottom line, check the width attribute of your parent view (in this case, it will be the ListView itself).

Answer (score 0):

You can change the height of your ListView to something, for example as below

```
android:layout_height = "XXdp"
```

make the XX enough to host the maximum number of items you allow to appear, if the number of items is greater, it will automatically scroll. If there are so few items, then then empty spaces exist.

Comment: how can I do it in program ( dynamically ) ?

Comment: if the number of items is greater, it will automatically scroll => you don't have to implement this, although you might want to implement getView() function to recycle the view.

If there are so few items, then then empty spaces exist.=> As far as I know, the height can't be shrinked dynamically, there's no function like setHeight() http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html